# How to get blob data in php?

Tags: php, ajax, blob

Blob is sound blob data.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('fname', 'test.wav');
fd.append('data', blob);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'upload.php',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
}).done(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
});
```

How to get "data" in upload.php?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  //lets assume you are uploading an .jpg image
  $filename = 'image.jpg';//<-- your filename and extension
  file_put_contents($filename, $_POST['data']);
  //now you have image.jpg
```

Comment: (int) $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] is large and
image.jpg is 0 byte. Why?

Comment: mmm.. so you are uploading an image?